# Bootstrap Changing Width of Downtown Menu

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to change the width of drowpdown menu in Bootstrap. Please guide where should i insert the custom CSS to change/reduce the width of drop-down menu.

```
   <body>
    <div class="container-fluid">



        <div class="dropdown">

            <button class="btn btn-info dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">MENU <span class="caret"></span></button>

            <ul class="dropdown-menu">

              <li class="dropdown-header">HEADER-1</li>
              <li>ITEM-1</li>
              <li>ITEM-1</li>
              <li>ITEM-1</li>
              <li class="divider"></li>
              <li class="dropdown-header">HEADER-2</li>
              <li>ITEM-1</li>
              <li>ITEM-1</li>




            </ul>

        </div>


      </div>





    </div>


  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrap's dropdown has some min-width to it. Change the `min-width` of drop-down menu so reduce its width.

```
.dropdown-menu {
    min-width: 125px;
  }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<style>
  .dropdown-menu {
    min-width: 125px;
  }
</style>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-info dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">MENU <span class="caret"></span></button>

    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li class="dropdown-header">HEADER-1</li>
      <li>ITEM-1</li>
      <li>ITEM-1</li>
      <li>ITEM-1</li>
      <li class="divider"></li>
      <li class="dropdown-header">HEADER-2</li>
      <li>ITEM-1</li>
      <li>ITEM-1</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

add custom class in your tag `<li>`, example

```
.dropdown-custom > .dropdown-menu {
    min-width:220px;
    padding:15px;
    color:red;
}
```

[try my fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5np4L1k0/14)